# Clarification about subclass in "MatchIT" package in R

Tags: r, matching

I am using 'MatchIt' package to match cases to controls. I would like to match by age and four other binary variables.

```
match_exact <- matchit(case_control~ age+var1+var2+var3+var4, cutpoints = list(age = 10),
                data = df, method="exact")
match_exact_data <- match.data(match_exact)
```

Then I extract the matched data and I would like to know the id's of cases to which control they were matched. Does the *subclass* column that was added to my df indicate that?

Thank you

Comment: Also, in the subclass strata I see more then one case. I would assume there would be one case and one or more controls. Does that makes sense?

Comment: Are you aware that the `cutpoints` argument doesn't work with `method = "exact"` and only works with `method = "cem"`? If you want coarsened exact matching, where you can specify the cutpoints yourself, you need `method = "cem"`. Please also see the discussion [here](https://github.com/kosukeimai/MatchIt/issues/77). You seem to have a misunderstanding about what exact matching is.